# Windows Azure in other countries

Tags: azure

I am from Lebanon and I want to sign-up to Windows Azure for free (or I want to purchase).
The problem is that my country is not listed, so I can't get a verification code through my phone number, and I don't know if my credit card will be accepted.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you REALLLY need MS Azure? How about Amazon Web Services (http://aws.amazon.com) or Google Cloud (http://cloud.google.com)?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Azure is only available in the following countries for now: Algeria, Argentina, Australia, Austria, Azerbaijan, Bahrain, Belgium, Brazil, Bulgaria, Canada, Chile, Colombia, Costa Rica, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Dominican Republic, Ecuador, Egypt, El Salvador, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Guatemala, Hong Kong, Hungary, Iceland, India, Indonesia, Ireland, Israel, Italy, Japan, Jordan, Kenya, Korea, Kuwait, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Macedonia (FYRO), Malaysia, Malta, Mexico, Montenegro, Morocco, Netherlands, New Zealand, Nigeria, Norway, Oman, Pakistan, Panama, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Poland, Portugal, Puerto Rico, Qatar, Romania, Saudi Arabia, Serbia, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, South Africa, Spain, Sri Lanka, Sweden, Switzerland, Taiwan, Thailand, Trinidad & Tobago, Tunisia, UAE, UK, United States, Uruguay, and Venezuela.

From June 21st this year (2012) it has been available in these countries: Belarus, Kazakhstan, Turkey, Ukraine and Russia.

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/faq/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you contact a friend with a US credit card and phone number, or any other allowed country, to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

One of my friends is Lebanese and lives in Beirut. He has a Windows Azure account through his **MSDN subscription**.